# Should I use function or function! in vim scripts?

Tags: vim

I think I understand the difference between `function` and `function!`: if a function with the same name already exists `function!` silently replaces it, but `function` yields an error.

I end up using `function!` always. Because if I use simple `function` sooner or later it returns and bites me with:

```
E122: Function my_lib#MyHandyFunction already exists, add ! to replace it
```

Are there any situations when one should use simple `function` without `!`?

Answer (score 6):

In scripts, it doesn't hurt to use `:function!`, but you should use *script-local* (`s:Foo`) or autoload-scoped (`myscript#Foo`) functions to properly namespace them. So, the override error for `:function` is helpful to alert you to redefinitions of *global* functions, but in scripts, you shouldn't need this precaution.

You *have* to use `:function!` when you want to reload the script during development (instead of restarting the whole Vim). (And plugins like my [ReloadScript plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1904) can deal with the include guards.)

Another empirical point: Most of the plugins I have use `:function!`, probably for the easy reload.

The same goes for `:command!` and `:normal!`, where (usually), the version with `!` should be used.

Comment: `:normal!` is about noremapping, not about reloading an already existing mapping.

Comment: @LucHermitte I know, it just sort of fits the pattern that the banged commands are usually preferable. Some people think the `!` is somewhat "dangerous" (maybe because it is in the most common command, `:w!`)

Answer (score 1):

You should normally use `function`. Doing such, you would at least recognize when there's a name collision.

When using `function!` by default, you don't have any feedback that you're about to override an existing function (i.e. **change existing functionality**)!

Just have a look at the error message you've posted:

```
E122: Function my_lib#MyHandyFunction already exists, add ! to replace it
```

This means: careful, dude! If you use `function!` now, the users of `my_lib#MyHandyFunction` will experience things they never expected!